# Grails and consume SOAP webservice

Tags: java, web-services, grails, soap, soap-client

Being fairly new to Grails i was wondering what people use to consume a webservice in Grails projects. So the client side of the system? Any recommendations? I see people using GroovyWS, Spring-WS etc.. What is a good and easy on to use?

Comment: I actually created my own project (https://github.com/jwagenleitner/groovy-wslite) and use it with Grails.  I wanted more control over the entire message (as opposed to wsdl parsing and proxies of GroovyWS).  Didn't want to put this as an actual answer to avoid looking like a shameless plug for my own project and it's too young of a project to say if it's good and easy to use. :)  But wanted to mention as an alternative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Grails CXF plugin here. Needed:

1. classloader workaround - `DynamicClientFactoryit` changed a current classloader;
2. and to code WS invocations by hand.

Besides that, the consumer code is pretty slim.

**Edit:** sorry, no more then this, and I'm not sure I'm not breaking and NDA yet:

#1:

```
def arrayOfLong = objectFactory.createArrayOfLong(XXX, ids)
result = client.invoke(methodName, arrayOfLong as Object[])
```

#2:

```
def dcf = DynamicClientFactory.newInstance()
def classLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader()

// create a WS client
// and assign end point address to it
def client = dcf.createClient(WSDL_URL, classLoader)
client.conduit.target.address.setValue(endpointUrl)

// reacquire classloader because 'createClient' changes it
def changedClassLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader()
def objectFactory = changedClassLoader.
    loadClass(FACTORY_CLASS_NAME).newInstance()
```

Comment: I was under the impression that cxf is used for providing webservices and not consuming. Why is the classloader workaround needed? Could you give also a small example on how you code the WS invocation? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Well, we're both providing and consuming, and tried to keep to one dependency.

Comment: I am trying both Groovy WS and the CXF approach, i generated my client using wsdl2java, placed the generated code inside the java folder and am now stumbling on the fact that i do not know what JAR files i need to copy into my lib folder to get things compiling succesfully.

Comment: Sorry, can't help you - I don't see your generated code's dependencies. We never used wsdl2java - our code is all dynamic. The client we use is created in a line `dcf.createClient(WSDL_URL, classLoader)`.

Answer (score 4):

[GroovyWS](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Using+WSClient+in+Grails) is very easy to use and has great documentation I would definitely recommend it.

Comment: IS Groovy WS on the same level as CXF? It seems indeed very easy!

Answer (score 1):

Using Grails 1.3.7 I am consuming my own web service with [WS-Client Grails plugin](http://www.grails.org/plugin/ws-client). It is actually based on GroovyWS, which in turn uses CXF. It is very easy to use at least in my simple scenario, where I only get Strings from the backend web service. I have no idea how it works with complex data types yet though.

I had never consumed or created a webservice before but using that plugin in the frontend and the [Grails CXF plugin](http://www.grails.org/plugin/cxf) in the backend I got a SOAP discussion between my grails apps in two days. You don't really need to use CXF or GroovyWS directly with the very nice ws-client plugin. Speed (of development) and simplicity.

Comment: At the time, no. But I haven't worked on the project since then, so I can't really say. As far as I know the project this was used in was actually never put into production as sometimes happens :)